# How to limit a .map()

Tags: javascript

How can I limit this MAP, so that I only search the first 3 items, cleanly?

```js
const Xx = actives.map(it => ({
    x: it.ticker,
    y: it.percent,
    label: it.percentual,
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, {id: 4}];

const Xx = arr.slice(0, 3).map(el => ({
  x: el.id,
}));

console.log(Xx)
```